# Deleted .eclipse folder

Tags: eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I deleted my .eclipse folder under users/xxxx/.eclipse and now my emulator will not load, nor can I update the ADT under eclipse.  Is there a way to rebuild it?  Why is it causing the emulator to hang (boot animation)?

Comment: I would recommend just re-installing eclipse. Not too difficult and you should still have all your projects intact. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend re-installing eclipse. This will keep your projects intact but you might have to re-install some plugins.

I am going to assume you are using a linux/unix OS based on .eclipse folder. Use the following to clear out the old installation.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge eclipse`

Then get the most recent version of eclipse from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.
Extract using a command like

```
tar -zxvf eclipse-SDK-4.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz
```

NOTE: There should be an eclipse folder under /usr/lib already backup and or delete that folder before following the next step.

If using linux move the resulting eclipse folder to /usr/lib.

Then you should be able to run your new version of eclipse by typing `eclipse` in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I got everything back up and running, I was just being impatient waiting for my emulator to load, (took about 27 minutes to fire up).  And I was trying to update to the NON-https link instead of the https.  

I'm on Windows 7 Pro, and with everything functioning I still don't have a .eclipse folder where I used to (even after several suggested reinstalls).  Odd I guess???  Thanks so much again for helping out a  noob!

Neal

Comment: Glad you got everything figured out! If you are still having trouble with your android emulator being slow you might want to look at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator